# How can I change my date format using org.joda.time.LocalDate in android studio?

Tags: android-studio, datetime, android-date, android-jodatime

Basically, I want to get the date of Monday from the current day of the week.
eg: today is Tuesday and I want a Monday date, I'll get that required date from the following code lines:

```
 val now = LocalDate()
 val monday: LocalDate = now.withDayOfWeek(DateTimeConstants.MONDAY)
        mondayDate = monday.toString()
```

But the problem is that I'm getting date format as **2021-05-24** and I want the date in such format **24-5-2021**.
Now how to change the date format to get the required date format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a formatter.

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("d-M-y");
    
    LocalDate now = new LocalDate();
    LocalDate monday = now.withDayOfWeek(DateTimeConstants.MONDAY);
    String mondayDate = monday.toString(dateFormatter);
    System.out.println(mondayDate);
```

Output is what you asked for:

> 24-5-2021